# Custom tab-completion in bash's `read`

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readline, read

Is there a way to "import" a list of words into bash's `read` builtin to have custom tab-completion? I've been writing a wrapper script for suckless' minimalist irc client "ii", and I don't have a way to tab-complete nicks.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure `bash` can't do that. But in `zsh`

```
foo() { 
 local -a compcontext
 compcontext=( ${(f)"$(</tmp/names)"} )
 vared -c -p 'Enter in user: ' user
}
```

Will generate a list of matches from a file with a single name on each line.

Or, if you want to complete words for read and not the input it reads; in bash
`complete -W "$(</tmp/names)"  read` will accomplish that.

Comment: What do you mean by "words for read and not the input"? Not sure I understand you. I know you can tab-complete file names with `read -e`, but I'd like to be able to tab-complete custom words.

Comment: Arguments for `read`, like completing the -e.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I might look into that zsh solution then. Bash would be preferred, though.

Comment: Just want to confirm that his is still true even as of bash 5.0. No manipulation with `complete` changes the behavior, the completion database is totally ignored by `read -e`.